# brunch asset target retaining folder structure

Tags: brunch

I am trying to convert an existing JS project currently using Grunt for building project over to Brunch.

I'm initially trying to make brunch work using existing directory structure.

```
app  
- images  
- less  
- scripts
```

I want to copy the images into public directly (ie. as assets).
I know I could move them to app/assets/images but I prefer not to change the structure yet.

brunch-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  conventions: {
    assets: [ '^(?:app)/(images/**/*)' ],
    // assets: [ /(?:^app\/images[\\/])/ ],
    // assets: [ '(images/**/*)' ],
    //assets: /images[\\/]/,
  }
}
```

I want the image files to get copied to public/images.
ie. keep the "images" directory name

But the best I can seem to manage (using that uncommented assets value) is copying to public/app/images.

The other attempts just copy the contents of app/images to public.
ie. so i get app/image.jpg instead of app/images/image.jpg

I was hoping the using the non-captureing grouping of the "app" part in the regex would maybe make it work, but didn't.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is a way late response but I've created a plugin for this called https://www.npmjs.com/package/copycat-brunch that helps you configure brunch and mantaining your file directory structure, it's all in the README

```
plugins:{
  copycat:{
    "fonts" : ["bower_components/material-design-iconic-font", "bower_components/font-awesome/fonts"],
    "images": ["someDirectoryInProject", "bower_components/some_package/assets/images"],
    verbose : true, //shows each file that is copied to the destination directory 
     onlyChanged: true //only copy a file if it's modified time has changed (only effective when using brunch watch) 
  }
}
```

Leaving this here in case it helps some else too :)